# LuaLaTeX : write latex "commands" to file

Tags: luatex, filesystem-access

I made a randomly chosen quiz machine using `LuaLaTeX` and `beamer` for audience part that produce a `pdf` containning one frame per question, one slide per second to show the count down: it make a `pdf` with multiple redundant pages.

I'd like to produce in parallel a digest form of this quiz, in article A4 format, with only the questions and the answers. All this stuff is stored in a lua table I use once to create the `beamer` `pdf` naturally, I can reuse it to produce the digest, but as far as I know, one can produce only one `pdf` at the time, I'd like to store the digest in a separate `digest.tex` file and compile it later.

What is the command or the trick that will redirect `tex.print` to a separated file, or to produce two different `pdf` files at once if it's possible ?

**Addition**

Let say, I have a `lua` table :

```
t = {"Valeur app. par défaut à l'unité",69841.68, 69841 }
```

In beamer I use a nodes in a tikz picture to show the question, see below. But I also want something like that in a separate file (article class) :

```
tex.print (t[1]..":".."\\num{"..t[2].."}\\hfill"..t[3])
```

To have a digest of the quizz.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a starter file?

Comment: It will be not minal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua has an `io` library that seems to work with LuaLaTeX. I don't really know what the recommended usage is though.

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Foo.

\directlua{
out = io.open('somefile.tex','a')
out:write('Hello world. ')
out:write('This is different')
io.close(out)
}

\input{somefile}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, even better :D

Comment: No need to close something at the end ?

Comment: @Tarass I just updated, after having that same thought.

Comment: Commented lines don't work : `\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
out = io.open('somefile.tex','a')
% out:write("\\documentclass{article}')
% out:write("\\begin{document}")
 out:write("Hello word")
% out:write("\\end{document}")
io.close(out)
}

\end{document}`

Comment: @Tarass I don't really know what I'm doing here. You can check out the `luacode` package, see if that has any features  that can help. If I come up with something later I'll update.

Comment: Ok you answered very well to my question, `\\` problem come from the fact that it can't be used in `directlua`, only in `luacode` or in a separate `lua` file.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use the standard `TeX` file handle routines such as `\newwrite` and `\newread` and `\openout` etc., letting `LuaLaTeX` write the code to the file as if should be written 'to' the current file (well, the TeX input processing assembly line ;-))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newwrite\luageneratedfile

\begin{document}  
\immediate\openout\luageneratedfile=foolua.tex
\immediate\write\luageneratedfile{%
\directlua{%
  tex.print("Hello World")
  }
}
\immediate\closeout\luageneratedfile
\end{document}
```

This example generates `foolua.tex`, the only content is "Hello World" here.

Comment: Commented lines don't work : `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\newwrite\luageneratedfile

\begin{document}  
\immediate\openout\luageneratedfile=foolua.tex
\immediate\write\luageneratedfile{%
\directlua{%
  tp = tex.print
%  tp("\\documentclass{article}')
%  tp("\\begin{document}")
  tp("Hello word")
%  tp("\\end{document}")
  }
}
\immediate\closeout\luageneratedfile
\end{document}`

Comment: Well, drop the commented lines then? ;-)

Comment: I want to write to the file the latex command. If I drop them, what the use ? ;-)

Comment: @Tarass: You did not write something about verbatim code

Comment: I'am a little confused. I never spoke about verbatim. Your code works well too except the \\ problem with directlua,but as I use a separate file for lua code, it came only beacause a test it with your example.

Answer (score 3):

Only the  backslash needs to be escaped:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
    function OpenFile(mode,name) out=io.open(name,mode) return end
    function CloseFile() io.close(out) return end
\end{luacode}   
\newcommand\OpenFile[2][a]{\luaexec{OpenFile('#1','#2')}}
\def\CloseFile{\luaexec{CloseFile()}}
\def\WriteLn#1{\luaexec{out:write('\string#1'.."\string\n")}}
\def\Write#1{\luaexec{out:write('\string#1')}}

\begin{document}
    Foo.

    \OpenFile[w]{somefile.tex}
    \WriteLn{Hello world from \\LaTeX. }
    \WriteLn{This is different}%
    \Write{Hello world $\\sqrt{1+x}$. }
    \Write{This is different}
    \CloseFile

    \VerbatimInput{somefile}

    \OpenFile{somefile.tex}
    \WriteLn{Hello world from \\LaTeX. }
    \WriteLn{This is different}%
    \Write{Hello world $\\sqrt{1+x}$. }
    \Write{This is different}
    \CloseFile
%   
    \VerbatimInput{somefile}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to write not only text but `latex` command. I tried to repeplace `This is different by` by `$\\sqrt{2}$`. It dosen't work. Nor `$\sqrt{2}$`

Comment: see my edited answer. Use package `fancyvrb`

Comment: It has to work with a lua table through lualatex, si my edited question.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll see what I can do

Comment: Thank you Herbert, `Torbjørn T.`'s works fine, I missused it. See my last comment.

Comment: Just for fun: I edited my answer